# Running reboot from a terminal does not require a password, how can I require one?

Tags: command-line, reboot

On Ubuntu 17.10 it looks like user can just run `reboot` without `sudo` and my computer just reboots. This does not feel safe to me and it is not what I am used to. Is there a way to disable this and require password?

Comment: The duplicate question does not address the full context of the question.

Comment: This only applies if you control all active sessions on the system. The dub marked question doesn't address this nor does suggesting changing well defined polkit rules that were well thoughtout and are intended functionality make for a very good idea.

Comment: @jdwolf, you could write an answer under the duplication question.

Comment: @pa4080 No because the "duplication question" Is an entirely separate question to this one. The linked question actually IS asking how do I get a specific behavior. This one asks it in the context of whether its secure. The existing behavior is secure no changes to polkit are needed.